# How to use google sign in flow with NestJS AuthGuard

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, nestjs, passport.js, google-signin

I am trying to implement google login from React app that on success goes to backend with the credentials and then backend stores the user data and returns JWT token.

I am using NestJS/passport lib and I am having problem setting it up.

I created GoogleOAuthGuard and GoogleStrategy.

So my flow is like this:

1. User click login button and does the google login in a popup.
   GoogleLogin button is from @react-oauth/google

```js
<GoogleLogin
               onSuccess={async ({ credential }) => {
                const tokens = await axios.post('backendurl/auth/login/google', {
                  credential,
                });

                console.log(tokens);
              }}
              onError={() => {
                console.log('Login Failed');
              }}
            />
```

2. backend has implemented AuthGuard which tries to redirect to google.account page. From there I get error in browser console that
   `Access to XMLHttpRequest (...) has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

My guess is that probably nestjs/passport is not made to handle only part of the usual sign in flow so it tries to do a redirect on the initial request from the browser. That redirect causes error above.

Any have working example of this use case? Its so hard to find a decent guide and example for this.